# C#:Overlapped Class

Tags: c#

I have been searching the concept of **Overlapped Class** but I haven't been able to find any suitable answer apart from [OverLapped Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.overlapped(v=vs.110).aspx) as an official document.
Can someone provide any blog or concept of overlapping class?

**Edit:** synchronous or asynchronous I/O operations are basically overlapped function.

Synchronous or asynchronous operation: A function that executed synchronously and it does not return until the operation has been completed even though the operation has not been completed. And the overlapped function is the operation can return immediately, even though the operation has not been completed. This enables a time-consuming I/O operation to be executed in the background while the calling thread is free to perform other tasks.

So as per my understanding, we are overlapping a function, not a class. Can we overlap a class as per the above definition?

If it is possible then what's the point of overlapping a class? And what is the use of this **overlapped class**?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: This is a near-literal duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50673885

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It might help if you add some context.  e.g What problem you're trying to solve with this "Overlapped Class"

Answer (score 1):

Overlapped Class appears to be referencing the Win32 native concept of a Overlapped Structure, and is not an inherent C# language feature which seems to be your misunderstanding (I don't blame you, it sounds like one!):

> Provides a managed representation of a Win32 OVERLAPPED structure,
> including methods to transfer information from an Overlapped instance
> to a NativeOverlapped structure.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342(v=vs.85).aspx

> For a general synchronization overview and conceptual OVERLAPPED usage
> information, see [Synchronization and Overlapped Input and Output and
> related topics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686358(v=vs.85).aspx).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686358(v=vs.85).aspx

> You can perform either synchronous or asynchronous (also called
> overlapped) I/O operations on files, named pipes, and serial
> communications devices. The WriteFile, ReadFile, DeviceIoControl,
> WaitCommEvent, ConnectNamedPipe, and TransactNamedPipe functions can
> be performed either synchronously or asynchronously. The ReadFileEx
> and WriteFileEx functions can be performed only asynchronously.

So overlapped classes are just the classes provided by the library to represent Overlapped Structures.

Comment: Yes, I think it is just a managed version of the data structure that is needed for certain win 32 calls.  If you’re not using those calls, you don’t need the structure.